# Batch processing with Windows Workflow

Tags: .net, sql-server, workflow, workflow-foundation

Can anybody please provide any links and/or recommendations for the processing of batch information with Windows Workflow.

Specifically, I am looking at an invoicing scenario where there are complex rules required for the generation of prices and I am looking to be able to read in excess of 50k rows of data from a SQL Server 2008 database and process these through a workflow to generate a price for each row which will then be written back to the database (against each row). The workflow will also need to lookup additional information from the database during the pricing process. The workflow itself is already defined and working as it is also used when a job is created to provide the initial estimate for the job.

I would also like to point out at this time that I already know processing through a stored procedure will be significantly faster, but I am looking at options for maintainability as well as speed. That said, all comments are welcome.

I am currently working with workflows in .NET 3.5, but I would also be interested to know if there are any enhancements coming with workflow/.NET4 that would improve performance in the scenario outlined above.

Thanks.